# How do I package static pages for Rails into a ruby gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I want to create some static pages which will be accessed out of RAILS_ROOT/public and package them in their own gem which I can include in multiple Rails applications.  They're really just error pages, but I want them to be the same across all my applications.  Is there a way to do this?

Comment: You have to use rails engine, https://guides.rubyonrails.org/engines.html

Answer (score 1):

Having an application inside an application is probably a use case for **engines**. They basically allow defining views, routes, controllers, even models without conflicting with the application that consumes the gem. In your case I assume you would mostly use the view and route part.

Official documentation (it's great): https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/engines.html

Examples of gems using routing:

1. devise: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise
2. ActionCable
3. UserImpersonate https://github.com/userimpersonate/user_impersonate2
4. Resque https://github.com/resque/resque

Comment: While I could make an engine work, I'm thinking I have to make a route, controller, and views.  This seems awfully heavy weight for a few static pages that could really just go in the "public" directory.  Is there another way that I could just package static pages in a gem and have them be used in a Rails app?